# Why don't block parameters in a here-doc work?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to figure out why the following code does not work in a here-doc string eval:

```
script = <<FILE

def i_feel(&block)
  block_given? ? "I feel #{ yield } :D" : "I don't know how I feel :/" 
end

i_feel                                  
# => "I don't know how I feel :/"

i_feel { 'great' }                   
# => "I feel great :D"
FILE

puts script

`<main>': no block given (yield) (LocalJumpError)
```

I know that part of the reason is the string interpolation. But how do I make it work? Try it without the here-doc first and see if it works?

Comment: There is nothing to yield, it is not in a method.  So the scope is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer and a little more about what my intended purpose is. You want to see what you just ran so this is the complete version.

```
script = <<FILE

def how_i_feel
  block_given? ? "I feel \#{ yield }." : "I don't know how I feel :/." 
end
#{ def how_i_feel
     block_given? ? "I feel #{ yield }." : "I don't know how I feel :/." 
   end }
how_i_feel
#{ how_i_feel }                                  

how_i_feel { 'great :D' }
#{ how_i_feel { 'great :D' } }    

FILE

puts script
```

What Victor said was right.
Here doc includes scope also.
In this case it is the interpolation of the interpolation.
Sounds a little confusing but just look at what level those brackets go to.
Notice also that we have to escape the original #{ yield } less it try to evaluate it.
That was what caused all the trouble in the first place.
Hope this helps.

And by the way this is just copied from https://github.com/JoshCheek/ruby-kickstart/blob/kevin_challenge/cheatsheets/blocks_procs_and_lambdas.rb

From that you can see that you don't need the &block parameter.

Comment: This is for those new to here doc http://rubyquicktips.com/post/4438542511/heredoc-and-indent

Answer (score 7):

You can avoid interpolation in a heredoc by surrounding the identifier with `'`:

```
script = <<'FILE'
something with #{interpolation} like syntax.
FILE

puts script
```

This will just print out the literal `something with #{interpolation} like syntax.` Without the `'` around `FILE` you would probably get an error (if `interpolation` was defined you wouldn’t).

You can also use `` ` `` (backticks) to execute the contents of the heredoc:

```
s = <<`SCRIPT`
echo foo
echo bar
SCRIPT
```

`s` will now contain the result of executing the heredoc – in this case the string `"foo\nbar\n"`.

Comment: This is way better than the answer I would've left. You taught me something new!

Comment: Note that within the backticks example you are not executing Ruby code, but shell code. If you truly want to evaluate arbitrary strings as Ruby code you'll need to use one of the eval methods.

Comment: Good hint there. Thanks. But I already knew about heredocs. You can do this too: script = <<file

Comment: The other good point you made was about eval strings. There good for cheep and dirty quickies but who wants to read those? Doesn't the here doc basically do the same thing but more eloquently?

Answer (score 1):

I think that I just figured it out.

```
script = <<FILE

def i_feel(&block)
  block_given? ? "I feel yield :D" : "I don't know how I feel :/" 
end

i_feel                                  
# => "I don't know how I feel :/"

i_feel { 'great' }                   
# => "I feel great :D"

FILE

puts script
```

Just remove the string interpolation brackets and here doc prints it just fine without them. I think I forgot about setting it up to interpolate is all. Oops! I'll get back to you all on this when I can.

Maybe now I can get something new from it. At least the error went away.
That will stop distracting me.